# UILongPressGestureRecognizer in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm currently working with "**Press and hold**" on a button, here is my code:

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();

    longp = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(LongPress);
    button.AddGestureRecognizer(longp);
}

public void LongPress()
{
    if (a == true)
    {
       a = false;
    }
    else
    {
       a = true;
    }
    // stop recognizing long press gesture here
}
```

The problem is since I'm running a toggle method to change a value, all it does is just spamming the method **LongPress**, how to I cancel or stop the holding after changing the value?

**Update**

I've managed to get it work, here is my code example:

```
public void LongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer g)
{
    if (g.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
    {
        if (a == true)
        {
            a = false;
        }
        else
        {
            a = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` as parameter to `LongPress` method , and  change its `State` when you want to stop it .

##### sample code

```cs
public void LongPress(UILongPressGestureRecognizer g)
{
    if (a == true)
    {
        a = false;
    }
    else
    {
        a = true;
    }

    // stop recognizing long press gesture here
    g.State = UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've managed to get it work. I've updated my code example.